# can mysql query returns empty or null set with error in it

Tags: php, mysql

i have mysql query which is like below:

```
"SELECT * FROM table where id=1 and f_id = 1"
```

whereas column f_id does not exist. what should this return in your opinion. 
as i am stuck here because it gives me a null set. and when i run this query in phpMyAdmin it gives an error.

Any Help!

Comment: If `f_id` does not exist this query will generate an error. This happens in PHP too, you're probably just not printing it.

Comment: If you get an error, the set will certainly be null because nothing was returned to populate it...

Comment: you both of were right. Thanks BTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query will not be executed when a column will not be found. You will get en error.

To print this error use assuming u use php as seen in your post tags:

```
mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id = '1' AND f_id = '1' ") or die(mysql_error(());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not executed.it gives you error like `Unknown cloumn f_id in where clause`

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM `table` where `id`='1' and `f_id` = '1'"
```

Try this one